# Low Level Keyboard Hooks installs automatically and slows down computer?

Tags: c#, desktop-application, keyboard-hook

I am using Keyboard Low Level hooks in a desktop application to monitor user activity. Code i am using for hooks is give below. 
In this code (upto my knowledge) when I have to start monitoring user activity I call `SetHook()` this will install hook and I can monitor keys pressed on keyboard. When I want to stop capturing keys i just call UnHook() method.

Problem is when my application starts (`SetHook()` method is not called yet) my application install hooks automatically and it slows down system. System hangs for for 2-3 seconds every 1 mint.

To diagnose the problem I commented out all the below mentioned code and installed application. Now system works absolutely fine.

I am not sure why is this happening?

1. Why my application start capturing keys even I did not called `SetHook()` method yet?
2. Is there is any other way to capture global keys without using hooks?

Code for Hooks:

```
public static class WinKeyCapture5   {

   private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
   private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
   private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
   public static DateTime LastKeyPressTime;

   public static void SetHook()
   {
       SetHook(_proc);
   }

   public static void UnHook()
   {
       UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
   }

   private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
   {
       using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
       using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
       {
           return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
       }
   }

   private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

   private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

   private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   {
       //if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
       //{
           int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
           //if (vkCode == 44)
               //ScreenCapture.Load();



           LastKeyPressTime = System.DateTime.Now;


       //}

       return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   }
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
       LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);
   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
       IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
   private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName); 
}
```

Comment: Responsiveness of this hook critically depends on how well you pump the message loop.  The code you didn't include.

Comment: @Hans Passant,

i am using hooks to calculate user inactive time. You can see   

> LastKeyPressTime = System.DateTime.Now; 

I am using LastKeyPressTime in my code to check when user pressed a button on keyboard.

I will also like to mention i am calling SetHook() method in click event of button.
Problem is i did not clicked that button yet, i just started the application and it slows down my system.

If i comment all above mention code and then run application than it does not slow down my system.

Comment: You must have to use hook or you can use an other solution to calculate user inactivity time ?

Comment: We can use any way to calculate inactivity time. Using Hook is not compulsory.